# Can teasel root cure Lyme?

Tags: medical-science, disease

I do not have Lyme disease but get bitten by ticks several times a year so it does have my interest. I read some claims that a 'tincture of teasel root extracts' or similar can be used to cure Lyme disease (i.e. infection with Borrelia Burgdorferi) or at least relieve symtpoms. However I seem to be unable to find any scientific evidence. Is there any?

- *Teasel Root is used for healing from Lyme Disease and for good reason*
  http://www.tiredoflyme.com/teasel-root.html
- *Matthew explains that instead of killing the bacteria itself, it actually changes the environment in the body in order to engage the body's own capabilities to kill off Lyme bacteria.* http://www.lyme-disease-research-database.com/lyme_disease_blog_files/mathew-wood.html
- *In Mr. Wood's experience, 100% of the Lyme patients he has treated with teasel have had immediate relief from symptoms* http://www.lymediseaseresource.com/Teasel.html (also contains a link to a book by said Mr. Wood)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short: There have been no clinical trials.

In December 2016, an article was published in a journal called *Alternative and Complementary Therapies*. That is normally a red flag, but this one had a surprising conclusion:

- *[Herbal Medicine for Lyme Disease and Other Tick-Borne Infections](http://online.liebertpub.com/doi/abs/10.1089/act.2016.29085.eya)*, Yarnell Eric. Alternative and Complementary Therapies. December 2016, 22(6): 257-265. https://doi.org/10.1089/act.2016.29085.eya

> *Dipsacus fullonum* (fuller's teasel) is used as a case study to show a promising herb that has simply no research on whether it helps people with Lyme disease or any tick-borne infection. [...] There remains a black hole in terms of supported herbal treatments for these infections that urgently needs to be filled with credible clinical trials.

So a journal article in *Alternative and Complementary Therapies* concludes there is no clinical research to defend the use of this alternative therapy, and this backs up my personal searches, including in the Cochrane database.

The closest I found was an abstract for [a dissertation for a Naturopath](https://scholarworks.bridgeport.edu/xmlui/handle/123456789/1432).